# Undefined local variable or method 'name'

Tags: ruby

Below is a program that implements a tree.

```
class Tree
    attr_accessor :children, :node_name

    def initialize(name_children=[])
        @children = children
        @node_name = name
    end

    def visit_all(&block)
        visit &block
        children.each {|c| c.visit_all &block}
    end

    def visit(&block)
        block.call self
    end
end

ruby_tree = Tree.new( "Ruby", [Tree.new("Reia"), Tree.new("MacRuby")] )

puts "Visiting a node"
ruby_tree.visit {|node| puts node.node_name}
puts 

puts "visiting entire tree"
ruby_tree.visit_all {|node| puts node.node_name}
```

When I run this code it errors at this line

```
ruby_tree = Tree.new( "Ruby", [Tree.new("Reia"), Tree.new("MacRuby")] )
```

The error I'm receiving is

```
tree.rb:6:in `initialize': undefined local variable or method `name' for #<Tree:0x007f94020249f8 @children=nil> (NameError)
from tree.rb:19:in `new'
from tree.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In your constructor, (initialize), why aren't you entering the variables children, and name as such instead of a children_name ? What it seems to me is that when you are trying to instantiate the class by creating the objects, when it goes to the initialize constructor, it does not find a name in there.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your `initialize` method accepts a single argument named `name_children`, but from the body of that method it looks like the underscore should have been a comma - `name, children`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem - line 6 `@node_name = name`. Where do you define that variable?

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, (initialize), why aren't you entering the variables children, and name as such instead of a children_name ? What it seems to me is that when you are trying to instantiate the class by creating the objects, when it goes to the initialize constructor, it does not find a name in there.

```
def initialize(name, children=[])
    @children = children
    @node_name = name
en
```

Comment: Thanks for help guys, I fixed up the typo.

Answer (score 0):

As you have define attr_accessor :name in your Model so there you have to define Children method in you model like as

```
def self.name
    # here will be you code which you want 
 end
```